# multi image picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

below is my code, i need to make the camera when pressed to add multiple images on the screen\containers
it shows errors without explaining why

```
    
         final ImagePicker imgpicker = ImagePicker();
          List<XFile>? imagefiles;
        
          openImages() async {
            try {
              var pickedfiles = await imgpicker.pickMultiImage();
              //you can use ImageCourse.camera for Camera capture
              if(pickedfiles != null){
                imagefiles = pickedfiles;
                setState(() {
                });
              }else{
                print("No image is selected.");
              }
            }catch (e) {
              print("error while picking file.");
            }
          }
          final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
        
         File? singleImage;
        
          final singlePicker = ImagePicker();
          final multiPicker = ImagePicker();
          List<XFile>? images = [];
           @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
            return DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              child: MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Harmattan',),
                home: Scaffold(
                  key: _scaffoldKey,
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      actions: [>>>>>>
                    
     
        
              SizedBox(height: 2),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(children: [Text('  enter image ',style: TextStyle(),),
                                      IconButton(onPressed: getMultiImages, icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt,size: 30,),color: Colors.lightBlue,),],),
                                ],),
        
                                       SizedBox(
                                         height: 5,
                                       ),
                                       Text(
                                         'Mohab Erabi',
                                         style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                       ),
                                       SizedBox(
                                         height: 10,
                                       ),
                                       Container(
                                         height: 1,
                                         width: double.infinity,
                                         color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                       ),
                                       SizedBox(
                                         height: 10,
                                       ),
                                       Text('You Can Add Phoots Here'),
                                       SizedBox(
                                         height: 20,
                                       ),
                                       Expanded(
                                         child: InkWell(
                                           onTap: () {
                                             getMultiImages();
                                           },
                                           child: GridView.builder(
                                               itemCount: images!.isEmpty ? 1 : images!.length,
                                               gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                   crossAxisCount: 3),
                                               itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                                                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                       color: Colors.white,
                                                       border: Border.all(
                                                           color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))),
                                                   child: images!.isEmpty
                                                       ? Icon(
                                                     CupertinoIcons.camera,
                                                     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                                   )
                                                       : Image.file(
                                                     File(images![index].path),
                                                     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                   ))),
                                         ),
                                       )
                                     ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),.......
        
                                 Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    //style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(side: BorderSide(width: 1,style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                                    //style: ButtonStyle(shape: OutlinedBorder()),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'save',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
        .........        
        
          Future getMultiImages() async {
            final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await multiPicker.pickMultiImage();
            setState(() {
              if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
                images!.addAll(selectedImages);
              } else {
                print('No Images Selected ');
              }
            });
          }
```

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 348 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

Comment: Can you provide complete structure of your code  that will reproduce the issue, also you can remove extra widgets that aren't necessary to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expanded widget has no bounds I think. If you have added this to a column wrap the column with a sizedBox of height and width same as the device

```
SizedBox(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
 child: Column(
  children : [
   Expanded(
       child: InkWell(
         onTap: () {
          getMultiImages();
          },
          child: GridView.builder(
           itemCount: images!.isEmpty ? 1 : images!.length,
           gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
           itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))),
                child: images!.isEmpty? Icon(
                   CupertinoIcons.camera,
                   color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                ): Image.file(File(images![index].path),                                                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ))),
          ),
      )
  ]
 ),
)
```

Comment: it does display one image now, and i want multiple. i tried adding containers, variables but seems like i should add sth else, sth more. can u please tell me how can i add more images ? is it in the androidx file ? but i think noty because i can access the gallery.

Comment: The images list should have all the images.. If you loop through the list you should get all images displayed

Comment: it does but the idea remains that i cannot upload it.   i tried editing . images is the variable with list of images, _file is for a single image "what i want to replace" 
  Future upload () async{
    if (images == null)
      return;
    String base64 = base64Encode(_file!.readAsBytesSync());
    print(base64);
    print(images);
    String imageName = _file!.path.split("/").last;
    print(imageName);
    setState(() {
      finalImageBase64 = base64;
      finalImageName = imageName;
    });
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000763/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-rest-api-in-flutter

Comment: it didnot help me , or can u guide me ? 
  void selectImages() async {
    List<int> imageBytes = _file?.readAsBytesSync() as List<int>;
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);

    final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await
    imgpicker.pickMultiImage();
  // String base64= base64Encode();
    if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
      imagefiles!.addAll(selectedImages);
    }
    print("Image List Length:" + imagefiles!.length.toString());
    setState((){
      finalImageBase64= base64Image;
  });}
 i need to post multiple images and show them afterwards..